# Keyboard not working on RDP session

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, remote-desktop

After connecting to remote session on RDP my keyboard is not working on the remote machine. I've tried every solution I've found including: disabling filter keys in Ease of Access panel, setting different keyboard options on RDP local resources, disabled "keyboard guard" on our antivirus software etc. I have no more ideas what could cause the problem. Sometimes rebooting the remote PC helps but the issue keeps coming back.

remote PC runs Windows 10 Pro, joined to a domain. I've tried to establish RDP from three different machines & versions of Windows (server, 7, 10) but none of them works.

any ideas?